# regex for date conversion in different format

Tags: regex

I have a date in the format `october 26, 2020` but it is displaying as `2020-10-26`.
we need to change form `2020-10-26` to `october 26, 2020`.

I can't see the examples of converting in these formats like I see lots of examples of changing the numeric format to other numeric formats but not this.

Thanks for any help with this.

Regards
Ash.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: You can parse the string as Date and convert it back to a string and defining the date format.